# Find MongoDB records where array field is empty

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to output a list of sketchid values for which tdata birthdate is not present/null, considering only the first birthdate in each tdata.

There are many fields in each collection, but I am only interested in two of them:

```
{ 
  "sketchid": NumberLong(51148),
  "tdata": "[
    { "birthdate": ["529718400"], ...},
    { "birthdate": null, ... }
  ]
}
```

I need to print the *sketchid* for each *tdata* in which the first *birthdate* is empty.
Note: A single *tdata* contains many *birthdate* fields, I need to check only the first *birthdate* field and if it is empty I need to output the *sketchid* for that set.

I have tried this, but I couldn't get the solution.

```
db.timeline.find({tdata:{birthdate:{$exists: true,  “$ne”: null }}},{sketchid})
```

To illustrate the data schema, the find() command (`db.timeline.find().pretty()`) gives the following output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ea7b9490e2a5b17c143b56"),
    "sketchid" : NumberLong(51147),
    "tdata" : "[{\\\"type\\\":\\\"dob\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Vishakha Singh\\\",\\\"year\\\":null,\\\"color\\\":null,\\\"content\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":[\\\"831254400\\\"],\\\"birthplace\\\":[\\\"Abu Dhabi, UAE\\\"],\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Taurus\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"timeline\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Cameo Role\\\",\\\"year\\\":[\\\"2014\\\"],\\\"color\\\":[\\\"#85330B\\\"],\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;Tamil movie Oru Oorla Rendu Raja&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,513,[null,0],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0]&quot;&gt;Tamil movie Oru Oorla Rendu Raja&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"timeline\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Noticable Flick\\\",\\\"year\\\":[\\\"2013\\\"],\\\"color\\\":[\\\"#21C8F5\\\"],\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;Neetu in Fukrey&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,513,[null,0],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0]&quot;&gt;Neetu in Fukrey&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"timeline\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Gained Recognition\\\",\\\"year\\\":[\\\"2010\\\"],\\\"color\\\":[\\\"#C90688\\\"],\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;Ashutosh Gowarikar\\'s Khelein Hum Jee Jaan Sey&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,47617,[null,0],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,[null,2,721024],&amp;quot;sans-serif&amp;quot;,11,null,1]&quot;&gt;Ashutosh Gowarikar&amp;#8217;s Khelein Hum Jee Jaan Sey&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"timeline\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Movie Debut\\\",\\\"year\\\":[\\\"2008\\\"],\\\"color\\\":[\\\"#FFCF00\\\"],\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;Hum Se Jahan&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,513,[null,0],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0]&quot;&gt;Hum Se Jahan&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"quote-card\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"vishakha singh\\\",\\\"year\\\":null,\\\"color\\\":null,\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;I am not really sophisticated but happy and chilled out&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,14915,[null,0],[null,2,16777215],null,null,null,null,0,null,null,0,null,[null,2,0],&amp;quot;helvetica&amp;quot;,11]&quot;&gt;I am not really sophisticated but happy and chilled out&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"}]"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ea7b9490e2a5b17c143b57"),
    "sketchid" : NumberLong(51148),
    "tdata" : "[{\\\"type\\\":\\\"dob\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Ali Fazal\\\",\\\"year\\\":null,\\\"color\\\":null,\\\"content\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":[\\\"529718400\\\"],\\\"birthplace\\\":[\\\"Lucknow, Uttar Pradesh\\\"],\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Libra\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"timeline\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Bollywood Appearance\\\",\\\"year\\\":[\\\"2016\\\"],\\\"color\\\":[\\\"#C90688\\\"],\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;Anand L. Rai\\'s Happy Bhaag Jayegi&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,47617,[null,0],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,[null,2,721024],&amp;quot;sans-serif&amp;quot;,11,null,1]&quot;&gt;Anand L. Rai&amp;#8217;s Happy Bhaag Jayegi&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"timeline\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"English Movie\\\",\\\"year\\\":[\\\"2015\\\"],\\\"color\\\":[\\\"#FFCF00\\\"],\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;Special Appearance in Furious 7&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,513,[null,0],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0]&quot;&gt;Special Appearance in Furious 7&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"timeline\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"First Lead Role\\\",\\\"year\\\":[\\\"2015\\\"],\\\"color\\\":[\\\"#B6D402\\\"],\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;Khamoshiyan&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,513,[null,0],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0]&quot;&gt;Khamoshiyan&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"timeline\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Supporting Role\\\",\\\"year\\\":[\\\"2014\\\"],\\\"color\\\":[\\\"#FF2305\\\"],\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;Bobby Jasoos with Vidya Balan&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,513,[null,0],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0]&quot;&gt;Bobby Jasoos with Vidya Balan&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"timeline\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"First Success\\\",\\\"year\\\":[\\\"2013\\\"],\\\"color\\\":[\\\"#85330B\\\"],\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;Fukrey&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,513,[null,0],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0]&quot;&gt;Fukrey&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"timeline\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Bollywood Debut\\\",\\\"year\\\":[\\\"2009\\\"],\\\"color\\\":[\\\"#21C8F5\\\"],\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;Special Appearance in 3 Idiots&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,513,[null,0],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0]&quot;&gt;Special Appearance in 3 Idiots&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"timeline\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"American Miniseries\\\",\\\"year\\\":[\\\"2009\\\"],\\\"color\\\":[\\\"#C90688\\\"],\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;Bollywood Hero&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,513,[null,0],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0]&quot;&gt;Bollywood Hero&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"timeline\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Screen Debut\\\",\\\"year\\\":[\\\"2008\\\"],\\\"color\\\":[\\\"#FFCF00\\\"],\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;Small role in the English language film The Other End of the Line&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,309761,[null,0],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,[null,2,721024],&amp;quot;sans-serif&amp;quot;,11,null,1,null,null,1]&quot;&gt;Small role in the English language film The Other End of the Line&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"},{\\\"type\\\":\\\"quote-card\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Ali Fazal\\\",\\\"year\\\":null,\\\"color\\\":null,\\\"content\\\":\\\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span data-sheets-value=&quot;[null,2,&amp;quot;I love being in love.&amp;quot;]&quot; data-sheets-userformat=&quot;[null,null,14915,[null,0],[null,2,16777215],null,null,null,null,0,null,null,0,null,[null,2,4144959],&amp;quot;georgia&amp;quot;,11]&quot;&gt;I love being in love.&lt;\\\\/span&gt;&lt;\\\\/p&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"birthdate\\\":null,\\\"birthplace\\\":null,\\\"zodiac\\\":\\\"Capricorn\\\"}]"
}
```

When I tried following commands I get the following errors

> db.timeline.find({tdata:{"birthdate":{$exists: true, “$ne”: null }}},{sketchid})
>   2016-08-19T12:02:14.665+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: illegal character @(shell):1:53
>
> db.timeline.find({tdata:{"birthdate\\":{$exists: true, “$ne”: null }}},{sketchid}) 
>   2016-08-19T12:02:53.357+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: unterminated string literal @(shell):1:25
>
> db.timeline.find({tdata:{\\"birthdate\\":{$exists: true, “$ne”: null }}},{sketchid})
>   2016-08-19T12:03:06.572+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: illegal character @(shell):1:25

Comment: please post the result of db.timeline.findOne() in your question so we can see the format of your collection. Then kindly explain what you want to query in a rather simple manner.

Comment: Hi i have post the result of db.timeline.find().pretty()

Comment: are the \\\ in your tdata actually a part of the collection of just a copy paste thing?

Comment: Actually in my collection

Comment: so then instead of using "birthdate" in your query you should use "birthdate\\\" i.e. find({tdata:{"birthdate\\\":{$exists: true,  “$ne”: null }}},{sketchid})

Comment: getting following errors > db.timeline.find({tdata:{"birthdate":{$exists: true, “$ne”: null }}},{sketchid})
2016-08-19T12:02:14.665+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: illegal character @(shell):1:53

> db.timeline.find({tdata:{"birthdate\\\":{$exists: true, “$ne”: null }}},{sketchid}) 
2016-08-19T12:02:53.357+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: unterminated string literal @(shell):1:25

> db.timeline.find({tdata:{\\\"birthdate\\\":{$exists: true, “$ne”: null }}},{sketchid})
2016-08-19T12:03:06.572+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: illegal character @(shell):1:25

Comment: my tdata field is string. so i need to modify the command according to it.can anyone guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the positional operator if you want to test only the first element of the tdata array.  Also depending on your version {$ne:null} doesn't always give what you'd expect.  You can check against the null type 10 instead:

```
db.timeline.find({"tdata.0.birthdate": {$exists:true,$not : { $type : 10 }} },{sketchid:1})
```

Comment: Hi, i have post the result of the command db.timeline.find().pretty()

Comment: it seems he doesnt want to test the first element of the array, but he wants the test the first birthdate in the array (where ever it may exist)

Comment: getting following errors > db.timeline.find({tdata:{"birthdate":{$exists: true, “$ne”: null }}},{sketchid}) 2016-08-19T12:02:14.665+0530 E QUERY [thread1] SyntaxError: illegal character @(shell):1:53 > db.timeline.find({tdata:{"birthdate\\\":{$exists: true, “$ne”: null }}},{sketchid}) 2016-08-19T12:02:53.357+0530 E QUERY [thread1] SyntaxError: unterminated string literal @(shell):1:25 > db.timeline.find({tdata:{\\\"birthdate\\\":{$exists: true, “$ne”: null }}},{sketchid}) 2016-08-19T12:03:06.572+0530 E QUERY [thread1] SyntaxError: illegal character @(shell):1:2

Comment: You do have special characters around $ne.  Those should be removed or changed to standard quotes.  Also, {sketchid} should be {sketchid:true}.  `db.timeline.find({tdata:{"birthdate":{$exists: true, "$ne": null }}},{sketchid:true})`

Comment: Hi, it is not working. my tdata field is a string. I am stuck here.